# (unsigned *) better than (unsigned int *) for parsing memory?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I understand the difference between unsigned and unsigned int. But my question is a bit different.

I am ioremaping(linux) a particular memory and i want to read the memory.
I did the following thig :

```
func()
{
    unsigned int *p;

    p = (unsigned int *)ioremap(ADDR,8*sizeof(unsigned int));
    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
       pr_err("p[%d] = %d", i, p[i]);
}
```

This works perfectly. But I see a standard code doing the same and using (unsidned *) instead of (unsigned int *). That is p is of `unsigned *p`.

```
func()
{
    unsigned *p;

    p = (unsigned *)ioremap(ADDR,8*sizeof(unsigned));
    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
       pr_err("p[%d] = %d", i, p[i]);
}
```

I would like to know if it is a good programming practice(platform independent code??). If yes please sate the reason.

Comment: "*I understand the difference between unsigned and unsigned int.*" -- Just what do you think the difference is? (There is none, other than spelling.) And you should use `%u` or `%x`, not `%d`, to print unsigned values.

Answer (score 3):

`unsigned` and `unsigned int` has no difference at all.

Therefor, `unsigned *` and `unsigned int *` has no difference at all.

---

Similarly, `long` is short for `long int`, `int` is short for `signed int`, etc. There is no difference in one to the other. The only exception to notice is that whether plain `char` is  signed or unsigned is implementation-defined, so it's not the same as `signed char`.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned` and `unsigned int` are the same type, so are pointers to them. The int is implicit.